# How to create a link to the record page using lwc?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am using [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) and would like to create a link to record's detail page when using the `<lightning-tile>` element.

**Question:**

How can I do this using the `href` attribute?

I have tried the following, but it fails to print a `<a href="/someid">` correctly.

Code:

**myApp.html**

```
<template>
   <!-- other code -->
    <template for:each={myAccounts} for:item="account">
            <div key={account.id} class="slds-col">
               <lightning-tile
                      label={account.Name}
                      href="/"+{account.Id}>
                    <p>here i go</p>
               </lightning-tile>
            </div>
        </template>
</template>
```

**myApp.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track
    myAccounts = [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "Abc Inc.",
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "Def Inc.",
        },
        {
            "Id": "3",
            "Name": "XYZ Inc.",
        },
        {
            "Id": "4",
            "Name": "WX Inc.",
        },
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) to resolve this using recommendation from @n30r3b3l. Also removed `href={account.Url}`

**myApp.html**

```
<template>
   <!-- other code -->
    <template for:each={myAccounts} for:item="account">
            <div key={account.id} class="slds-col">
               <lightning-tile
                      label={account.Name}>
                    <p>here i go</p>
                    <lightning-button variant="Base" label="Record View" onclick={viewRecord} value={account.Id}></lightning-button>
               </lightning-tile>
            </div>
        </template>
</template>
```

**myApp.js**

```
viewRecord(event) {
        // Navigate to Account record page
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                "recordId": event.target.value,
                "objectApiName": "Account",
                "actionName": "view"
            },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are attempting to do an expression evaluation in the markup, which I don't think is supported in LWC at this time. You will likely need to do something like

**myApp.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
@track
myAccounts = [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Abc Inc.",
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Def Inc.",
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "XYZ Inc.",
    },
    {
        "Id": "4",
        "Name": "WX Inc.",
    },
];

    myAccounts.forEach(function(item){
        item.Url = '/' + item.Id;
    }
    );
}
```

**myApp.html**

```
<template>
    <!-- other code -->
    <template for:each={myAccounts} for:item="account">
        <div key={account.id} class="slds-col">
           <lightning-tile
                  label={account.Name}
                  href={account.Url}>
                <p>here i go</p>
           </lightning-tile>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

But It would probably be better to use the [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) from lightning/navigation to build the record url instead of just doing `/<accountId>`

Comment: I did end up using `NavigationMixin` based on your solution